# Elemento específico em uma array em Assembly no AVR

Tags: assembly

No seguinte trecho de códiogo:

```
    ldi     r16,255
    out     IO(DDRB),r16
    ldi     r30,1
    subi    r30,lo8(-(array))
    sbci    r31,hi8(-(array))
    ld      r24,Z
    out     IO(PORTB),r24
```

porque há um -(array) dentro de ambos lo8 e hi8 ?
E porque as instruções subi e subci são usadas aqui ?
Como que o endereço para o 2º elemento consegue ser obtido disso ?
Eu estou usando o avr-gcc.

Answer (score 1):

O objetivo é calcular `array+1`. No primeiro momento o valor `1` é carregado no `r30`. Imagino que algum código antes zere o registrador `r31` pois não há nada ai que o faça. Na sequencia deve-se adicionar o endereço da array (16 bits) no par de registradores `r30` e `r31`. O problema é que o assembly AVR **não tem uma instrução para somar imediatos**. Então em vez de fazer `1+array`, ele fez `1-(-array)`.

```
subi    r30,lo8(-(array))
sbci    r31,hi8(-(array))
```

As duas instruções de subtração capturam o primeiro e segundo byte do endereço negado da array e operam com os registradores que contém agora o número `1`. A segunda instrução é `sbci` para transportar o carry da primeira.